# Pivot table on a column which contains two indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have an initial dataframe that looks like this:

```py
   Row tags                  Values
0  4                         100
1  100101 - Hospital A.xls   30
2  100195 - Hospital B.xls   30
3  100105 - Hospital C.xls   40
4  5                         50
5  100101 - Hospital A.xls   25
6  100195 - Hospital B.xls   25
```

Whenever there is a number in `Row tags` (i.e. without the .xls ending), its value corresponds to the sum of the rows that follow beneath it. There can be an arbitrary number of rows that follow.

I would like to pivot on those numbers, to obtain the **desired output**:

```py
   Code   Hospital                  Values
0  4      100101 - Hospital A.xls   30
1  4      100195 - Hospital B.xls   30
2  4      100105 - Hospital C.xls   40
3  5      100101 - Hospital A.xls   25
4  5      100195 - Hospital B.xls   25
```

**What I have tried to do:**

As there is a pattern in `Row tags` that can be captured with a Regex, I created an intermediary table with a boolean column which distinguishes the entries that are numbers with those that end with .xls.

```py
   Row tags                  Values   Regex pattern
0  4                         100      False
1  100101 - Hospital A.xls   30       True
2  100195 - Hospital B.xls   30       True
3  100105 - Hospital C.xls   40       True
4  5                         50       False
5  100101 - Hospital A.xls   25       True
6  100195 - Hospital B.xls   25       True
```

But I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Row tags': ['4', '100101 - Hospital A.xls', '100195 - Hospital B.xls', '100105 - Hospital C.xls', '5', '100101 - Hospital A.xls', '100195 - Hospital B.xls'],
    'Values': [100, 30, 30, 40, 50, 25, 25]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

m = df['Row tags'].str.contains('.xls')
df = df.assign( Code = df['Row tags'].where(m == False).ffill() )[m]

print(df[['Code', 'Row tags', 'Values']])
```

```
  Code                 Row tags  Values
1    4  100101 - Hospital A.xls      30
2    4  100195 - Hospital B.xls      30
3    4  100105 - Hospital C.xls      40
5    5  100101 - Hospital A.xls      25
6    5  100195 - Hospital B.xls      25
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need pivot for that, simply search for numbers only in `Row tags` and adjust dataframe accordingly:

```py
nums = df["Row tags"].str.extract(r"^(\d+)$")
df["Code"] = nums.ffill()
df = df[nums.isna().values]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                  Row tags  Values Code
1  100101 - Hospital A.xls      30    4
2  100195 - Hospital B.xls      30    4
3  100105 - Hospital C.xls      40    4
5  100101 - Hospital A.xls      25    5
6  100195 - Hospital B.xls      25    5
```